# Separating always_comb processes for speed?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

With a couple of variable definitions:

```
var integer a;
var integer b;
var integer c;
var integer base;
```

is this combinational process

```
always_comb begin
    a = base + 2;
    b = base + 3;
    c = base + 5;
end
```

taking longer than these combinational processes

```
always_comb begin
    a = base + 2;
end
always_comb begin
    b = base + 3;
end
always_comb begin
    c = base + 5;
end
```

given that the RHS is completely evaluated and assigned to the LHS before the next statement is executed? (I am aware that `assign` would be much better here, that is not my point)
I am talking about execution (after synthesis and implementation) on an  FPGA. My point is: If blocking statements are *really* blocking, even if the variables do not depend on each other, the separated case should result in lower latency until `c` is stable after `base` has changed.
What does the specification say about this?

Comment: That performance difference does not make sense. `base` is the only variable in the sensitivity list. Performance wise the should be very similar, maybe the single always block slightly faster. Unless your simulator is intelligently dividing the work across multiple processors, I cannot imagine how the single always block would have noticeably lower performance. Maybe the `(*)` is doing something; `always_comb` should not have a sensitively list. Otherwise it sounds like an issue with your specific simulator or the code you are showing is not accurately reflecting your issue.

Comment: How much performance improvement do you see with single always blocks? Is it significant improvement?

Comment: I am talking about execution on real hardware (updated the question to reflect that). Greg, you are right, I removed the sensitivity lists.

Comment: The MWE does not make much sense on its own, but having 50 blocking statements after one another each adding latency or 50 in parallel would make a huge difference, given that the presumption that they are really blocking even without dependence on each other is true.

Answer (score 0):

> …given that the RHS is completely evaluated and assigned to the LHS before the next statement is executed?

This assumption is inaccurate. The code samples you have provided are completely equivalent, and will synthesize to identical RTL.

`always_comb` generates combinational logic. There is no sequencing implied -- when one of the inputs (like `base`) changes, all three outputs will change to the new result as quickly as possible, subject to propagation delays. There is no guarantee of which one (if any) will stabilize on a new value first.

For what it's worth, the same principle largely applies to `always_ff` as well. If these code samples used `always_ff` instead of `always_comb`, they would also be equivalent; after `base` changed, a single clock edge would cause all three values `a`, `b`, and `c` to update to the new sums.

Comment: In "10.4.1 Blocking procedural assignments", IEEE Std 1800-2009 says "A blocking procedural assignment statement shall be executed before the execution of the statements that follow it in a sequential block (see 9.3.1).", so how is that assumption inaccurate?

Comment: @apriori The Verilog standard is a bit of a weird place. It's written primarily from the perspective of software simulators, not hardware synthesis -- many of the behaviors it describes cannot be reproduced in hardware. This is one such situation.